# Data Quality Checks REDCap

Tags: redcap

I am trying to use the inbuilt REDCap's data quality checks to validate the data entry that is done into the project.

1. `if(mid([colive_id],1,2)=mid([subjid],3,2),1,0)`
   Value for colive_id: 02CD00021 & subjid: IB02-0020
2. 

Option 1 : `if([mhcat]="34000006",if(mid([colive_id],3,2)="CD",1,0),if(mid([colive_id],3,2)="UC",1,0))`

Option 2 :
`(([[mhcat]]<>"34000006") and (mid([colive_id],3,2)<>"CD")) or (([mhcat]<>"64766004") and (mid([colive_id],3,2)<>"UC"))`
Value for mhcat: 34000006 & colive_id: 02CD00021

3. `if(mid([subjid],4,1)=[siteid],1,0)`
   Value for subjid: IB02-0020 & siteid: 2

I quite not able to figure what is the issue with the above formula's which makes the rules to fail.

[image: Data Quality Violation]